# Sub make error 2

Tags: compiling, make

I try to build some rom and I got this error. Do you know what directory makes this error?

```
  CC      net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_raw.o
  CC      net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_ah.o
  CC      net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_MASQUERADE.o
  CC      net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_NETMAP.o
  CC      net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_REDIRECT.o
  CC      net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_REJECT.o
  CC      net/ipv4/netfilter/arp_tables.o
  CC      net/ipv4/netfilter/arpt_mangle.o
  CC      net/ipv4/netfilter/arptable_filter.o
  LD      net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_conntrack_ipv4.o
  LD      net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_nat.o
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/code-factory.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/code-stubs.cc
target thumb C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/code-stubs-hydrogen.cc
  LD      net/ipv4/netfilter/built-in.o
  LD      net/ipv4/built-in.o
  LD      net/built-in.o
make[1]: *** [sub-make] error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/fe/android/aoso/kernel/lge/gproj'
make: *** [TARGET_KERNEL_BINARIES] error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

#### make failed to build some targets (57:23 (mm:ss)) ####
```